# Relationship between tagTemplate and newVersionCommitMessage options in gradle-release-plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-release-plugin

It's a minor thing, but in my build.gradle file I have gradle-release-plugin configured like:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.3.4'
}    

release {
    tagTemplate = 'release-${version}'
    scmAdapters = [
        net.researchgate.release.GitAdapter
    ]
}
```

New version commit message is like: "[Gradle Release Plugin] - new version commit: 'release-0.8'.". How can I get rid of this "release-" part in the message?

Answer (score 0):

Hey the message is build like this

```
release {
    tagTemplate = '${version}'
}
```

Will print "[Gradle Release Plugin] - new version commit: '0.8'."

If you want you can also do

```
release {
    tagTemplate = '${version}'
    newVersionCommitMessage = 'New version: '
}
```

Will print "New version: '0.8'."